# Input required if any option from dropdown selected

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have an invoice form contain a table consist of 3 columns: kode_barang (ItemID), nama_barang (ItemName), and qty(quantity).Let's say it just have 2 rows:

```
<form name="invoice" action="insert3.php" method="post">
<table id="theTable" border="1">
   <thead>
       <tr>
          <th> Kode Barang </th>
          <th> Nama Barang </th>
          <th> Qty </th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td><select name="kode_barang[]" id="kode_barang0" required /> </td>
         <td><input type="text" name="nama_barang[]" id="nama_barang0" required /></td>
         <td><input type="text" name='qty[]' required /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td><select name="kode_barang[]" id="kode_barang1" /> </td>
         <td><input type="text" name="nama_barang[]" id="nama_barang1" /></td>
         <td><input type="text" name='qty[]' /></td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

ItemID is a dropdown menu which it's option get populated dynamically from another table. All fields in the first row are required since it will be no a new invoice if it's empty.

But I'm having problem with the second row. If user select an item, then they can submit the form if only `ItemName` and `Qty` are filled. I've searched around and found several similar questions like this, but none of the answers work for me, or may be I just don't understand it. This is my non-working attempt:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

var $code = $('#kode_barang1'),
    $qty = $('#qty1'),
    $price = $('#harga_beli1');

var validator = $('#faktur').validate({
    debug: true,
    rules: {
        kode_barang[]: {
            required: function (element) {
                return $qty.val().length > 0 || $price.val().length > 0;
            }
        },
        qty[]: {
            required: function (element) {
                return $code.val().length > 0 || $price.val().length > 0;
            }
        },
        harga_beli[]: {
            required: function (element) {
                return $code.val().length > 0 || $qty.val().length > 0;
            },
            /* verify if confirmation is ok */
            equalTo: $np
        }
    },
    messages: {}
    });
});
```

Would anybody please help me with this? Thank you.

Comment: object property names with special characters in them must be quoted

Comment: @charlietfl still no luck :(

Comment: So, To consider a simple example, Your question is: **if a drop-down is "yes", you want another text-field to be mandatory, otherwise not.** Am I right?

Comment: @RupinderSingh just select any option from the dropdown, and another text-field to be mandatory, otherwise not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what you want but with two simple fields. Let me know if you need help understanding anything.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function isMandatory(){
        var dropDownElement = document.getElementById('dropdown');
        if(!dropDownElement){ // check if dropdown element exists
            return false;
        }
        if(dropDownElement.value == ""){ // check if value is selected in dropdown
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    function submitForm(){
        var fieldElement = document.getElementById('someField');
        if(!fieldElement){ // check if textfield element exists
            return;
        }
        if(isMandatory() && fieldElement.value == ""){
            alert("Field is mandatory!"); // or show message in a div
        }
        else{
            // do something
        }
    }
</script>
<div>
    <select id="dropdown">
        <option value="">--select--</option>
        <option value="item-1">item-1</option>
        <option value="item-2">item-2</option>
    </select>
    <input id="someField" type="text" />
    <input type="button" value="submit" onclick="submitForm();" />
</div>
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks.